# How to insert to database using php?

Tags: php, forms, insert, mysqli

I'm very new to php and I really want to learn it. I'm learning from w3school, but I can't manage to do this (saving to database)... I also tried specifying the values in the .php and managed not to get error but it did not save in the database. Please tell me what is wrong in this.

```
<form action="submit.php" method="POST">
    <p>Name:<input type="text" name="name"/></p>
    <p>Email:<input type="text" name="email"/></p>
    <p>Message:<textarea rows="3" cols="1" name="message"></textarea></p>
    <a href="submit.php">Submit</a>
</form>
```

---

PHP File

```
<?php 
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","kellywood");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to Database";
} else {
    echo "Connected";
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO kellywood (messages.name, messages.email, messages.message) VALUES ('$_POST[name]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[message]')");

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

### No error, and I specified the values but it did not save in the database.

```
<?php 
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","kellywood");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to Database";
} else {
    echo "Connected";
}

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO kellywood(messages.name, messages.email, messages.message) VALUES ('Peter', 'Griffin',35)");


mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Sorry for the noob question but i'm very new in php... Please help

Comment: I'd suggest not using w3school to learn. It's not that good. If you're really interested, look into PDO prepared statements as it's safer and it'd be better for you to get started with that than learn bad habits that you have to later fix.

Comment: Just change this `messages.name, messages.email, messages.message` to this `name, email, message` I guess that your table kellywood just have this fields On your insert statement

Comment: @Niketa Using PDO doesn't protect one from bad habits. Mysqli is perfectly good. I have seen some truly awful uses of prepared statements created using PDO.

Comment: @jorge, still error, "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' in C:\wamp\www\For Allied Web\submit.php on line 10"

Comment: Try this: $sql = "INSERT INTO kellywood (name, email, message) VALUES ('" .$_POST['name'] . "','" . $_POST['email'] . "','" . $_POST['message']"')";

Comment: @jorge, "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in C:\wamp\www\For Allied Web\submit.php on line 10"

Comment: Sorry I miss a dot at the end: $sql = "INSERT INTO kellywood (name, email, message) VALUES ('" .$_POST['name'] . "','" . $_POST['email'] . "','" . $_POST['message'] . "')";

Comment: kellywood is the database.  it should be INSERT INTO tablename...which is "messages".  INSERT INTO messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things that are incorrect.

First:

```
<a href="submit.php">Submit</a>
```

which should be a button and not a link:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
```

And based on a comment that was made: *"database is kellywood, messages is the table."*

This:

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO kellywood(messages.name, messages.email, messages.message)
VALUES ('Peter', 'Griffin',35)");
```

Should be:

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO messages (name, email, message) 
VALUES ('Peter', 'Griffin',35)");
```

**However** and based on your input variables, it should resemble more like this:

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO messages (name, email, message) 
VALUES ('" . $name . "', '" . $email . "', '" . $message . "')");
```

While assigning your input variables such as:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
```

---

**Rewrite:**

```
<?php 
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","kellywood");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to Database";
} else {
    echo "Connected";
}

$name = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$email = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$message = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['message']);

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO messages (name, email, message) 
VALUES ('" . $name . "', '" . $email . "', '" . $message . "')");

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

---

Or you can use:

```
<?php 
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","kellywood");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to Database";
} else {
    echo "Connected";
}

$name = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$email = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$message = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['message']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO messages (name, email, message) 
VALUES ('" . $name . "', '" . $email . "', '" . $message . "')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

else {
echo "SUCCESS!";
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

**HTML form**

```
<form action="submit.php" method="POST">
    <p>Name:<input type="text" name="name"/></p>
    <p>Email:<input type="text" name="email"/></p>
    <p>Message:<textarea rows="3" cols="20" name="message"></textarea></p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Both of the above worked on my server, using VARCHAR(255) for all 3 columns.

Columns: `name` - `email` - `message`

Answer (score 2):

Try using a button type="submit", instead of the href tag.

Comment: I tried, an new error occured, "SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for"

Comment: That signifies a coding error somewhere.  ive seen it if HTML code works it's way into PHP code.  Can you post your new code sample?

Comment: Your PHO also needs some more error checking, like wrapping the insert code in: "if (isset($_POST['submit']) {  ///sql stuff here }

Comment: just to clarify...kellywood is the name of BOTH the database AND the table?  it's fine if it is, just making sure that's not a mistake.

Comment: replace your sql line with this:

$name = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$email = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$message = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['message']);

$result = $con->query("INSERT INTO messages (name, email, message) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$message'") or die (mysqli_error());

Comment: database is kellywood, messages it the table.